# Semaphore is acquired only by one process

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm trying to refactor my C code for POSIX standard. Apparently i got deadlock, that comes down to this simple code. Semaphore should be shared between two processes, but unfortunately its owned by process that has created it.

creator

```
sem_t * mutex;

  if ((mutex = sem_open (key_trucker, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) == SEM_FAILED) {
       perror ("sem_open"); exit (1);
    }

    int val;
    sem_getvalue(mutex,&val);

    if(val == 0 ){
      sem_post(mutex);
    }

  time_t currtime;
  while(1){
    sem_wait(mutex);
    time(&currtime);
    sleep(1);
    printf("%s",ctime(&currtime) );
    sem_post(mutex);
  }
```

process that shares semaphore

```
sem_t * mutex;

  if ((mutex = sem_open (key_trucker, 0 )) == SEM_FAILED) {
       perror ("sem_open"); exit (1);
        }

  time_t currtime;
  while(1){
    sem_wait(mutex);
    time(&currtime);
    printf("%s",ctime(&currtime) );
    sleep(1);
    sem_post(mutex);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The semaphore, to be shared between processes, needs to be a 'named' semaphore.  Such a name starts with a '\'.  The semaphore also needs to be destroyed, eventually, otherwise the second time a process calls `sem_open()` it will fail and set 'errno' to `EXIST` (or similar)  So the code also needs (after noting that the call failed) to check the value of `errno`

Comment: Wouldn't shared memory be an alternative to named semaphores?

Comment: @rcgldr,   Shared memory would be a workable alternative, however, the posted code is NOT using shared memory